# Filtro função php pdo

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

Estou com uma função php que me retorna numa tabela html todas placas **NrPlaca** porem eu precisaria por um filtro na função do php para mostrar na tabela apenas as placas que no **DsTpVeiculo** são bitruck, gostaria de algumas dicas de como fazer.Segue imagem do banco de dados:[image: Tabela banco de dados GTCLogist]

Função php:

```
class ProgDAO{

  private $conn;

  public function __construct($connection) {
      $this->conn = $connection;
  }

  public function ListaTodos(){
          $results = array();
          $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
              'SELECT * FROM GTCLogist'
          );
          $stmt->execute();
          if($stmt) {
              while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                  $prog = new Prog();
                  $prog->setplaca($row->NrPlaca);
                  $prog->setmot(stripslashes($row->DsMotorista));
                  $results[] = $prog;
              }
          }
      return $results;
  }
```

}

Table que mostra os dados:

```
    <table  border="1" width="30%">
            <tr>
                <th>BITRUCK</th>
                <th>Motorista</th>
                <th>Data Saída</th>
                <th>Origem</th>
                <th>Destino</th>
                <th>Prev. Cheg. Dest</th>
                <th>Carga/Manifesto</th>
                <th>Adiantamento Fincanceiro</th>
                <th>Agendas</th>
                <th>Malote</th>
                <th>Obs</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
                    foreach ($controller->listarEmail() as $objProg) {
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $objProg->getplaca(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $objProg->getmot(); ?></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>

        </table>
```

Comment: Pode ser no SQl não? Tem que ser feito no php mesmo?

Comment: É, gostaria que fosse no php mesmo mas se tiver uma outra opção aceito também.

Comment: Você precisa mesmo trazer a tabela inteira do banco? Senão, basta alterar sua SQL para `SELECT * FROM GTCLogist where DsTpVeiculo ='Bitruck'`.

Comment: Pode criar um método novo, que faz um `WHERE` no campo desejado ou usar o método com um parâmetro que informa o valor a ser buscado.

Comment: Ou caso queira fazer no php mesmo, pode colocar um `if($row->DsTpVeiculo == 'Bitruck')` dentro do `while`, mas isso é desperdicio da query ao banco, já que você pode trazer filtrado diretamente dele.

Comment: Tentei mudar o select pois deu erro no mesmo:  **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Bitruck' (T_STRING) in DAO\progDAO.php on line 14**

Comment: Você escapou as aspas? `'SELECT * FROM GTCLogist where DsTpVeiculo = \'Bitruck\''`

Comment: Justo haha, não sabia isso da contra barra. Me ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode criar um método novo para listar as placas por tipo, a diferença é que esse método recebe um parâmetro, o qual será usado na clásula `WHERE`

```
public function ListaPorTipo($tipo){
    $results = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM GTCLogist WHERE DsTpVeiculo = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($tipo));
    if($stmt) {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $prog = new Prog();
        $prog->setplaca($row->NrPlaca);
        $prog->setmot(stripslashes($row->DsMotorista));
        $results[] = $prog;
    }else{
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    }
    return $results;
}
```

E a chamada fica algo como:

```
<?php
$prog = new ProgDAO ($conexao);
$itens = $prog->listaPorTipo('bitruck');
```

Comment: Por questão de organização e reusabilidade, esta forma é realmente a mais apropriada. +1

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu uma grande ajuda. Era isso mesmo.

Comment: Só uma duvida, não estou conseguindo chamar a função estou usando MVC, preciso criar uma função dentro da class na model para chamar ?

Comment: @Kevin.F, a função deve  ser criada na classe `ProgDAO`

Comment: @rray sim certo, porem essa chamada onde deve ser posta ?

Comment: @Kevin.F coloca no controller que faz essa pesquisa, aí ele chama o DAO pega os valores e repassa para view(html).

Comment: @rray no controller estou usando isto:
`class Comando {
 
 private $conn;
        
         public function __construct($connec) {
         $this->conn = $connec;
     }

         public function listarTodos(){
   $dao = new ProgDAO($this->conn);
   return $dao -> ListaTodos();
  }
}



` um metodo construct, no caso teria que ter uma function dentro da class comando **listarPorTipo** não ?

Comment: @Kevin.F isso mesmo,

Comment: Agora foi rs, Vlw.